# Redraw On Touch

Tags: android

Hello All,
              I have erased an image using `mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_OUT));` on touch events, now I want to undo this drawing (basically removing the path which were drawn earlier) on touch events. I don't want to draw the whole path at once instead clear the path point wise as finger move above these paths. I have stored all tha paths in an array list. Any Idea how can I do this. I'm able to remove the whole path but not point wise redrawing.